# How to have multiple resources with the same base class name in ApiPlatform

Tags: php, symfony, openapi, api-platform.com

I have two resource classes, representing different things with different properties. I want to name them the same, but put them in different namespaces. For example, I have a `Foo\Item` and a `Bar\Item`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\ApiResource\Foo;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get;

#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(),
    ],
    routePrefix: 'foo',
    uriTemplate: '/item/{key}',
)]
class Item
{
    #[ApiProperty(openapiContext: ['example' => 'foo key'])]
    public string $key;

    #[ApiProperty(openapiContext: ['example' => 'foo description'])]
    public string $description;
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\ApiResource\Bar;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get;

#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(),
    ],
    routePrefix: 'bar',
    uriTemplate: '/item/{id}',
)]
class Item
{
    #[ApiProperty(openapiContext: ['example' => 'bar id'])]
    public string $id;

    #[ApiProperty(openapiContext: ['example' => 'bar name'])]
    public string $name;
}
```

This works fine from an operational standpoint, all of my endpoints work as expected. However, since ApiPlatform uses the resource's *base* class name as the OpenApi schema name, the autogen documentation is incomplete -- it contains only the alphabetically first item:

```json
{
   "components" : {
      "schemas" : {
         "Item" : {
            "deprecated" : false,
            "description" : "",
            "properties" : {
               "id" : {
                  "example" : "bar id",
                  "type" : "string"
               },
               "name" : {
                  "example" : "bar name",
                  "type" : "string"
               }
            },
            "type" : "object"
         },
```

This results in both `Item` resources having documented endpoints but only one of them having a documented schema:
[image]

Questions:

- Am I out of luck here? Will I have to rename my resource classes to be unique across all namespaces, like `Foo\FooItem` and `Bar\BarItem`, and subsequently have the docs reflect that?
- Is there perhaps some way to instruct ApiPlatform to separate/group namespaces, such that all the `/api/foo/*` endpoints belong to one schema group and all the `/api/bar/*` endpoints belong to a different one, and they each get their own set of docs?
- Should this be considered a bug? If this is not supported, and resource names need to be unique, should ApiPlatform have detected these conflicting names and issued an error?

Comment: You can add tag key after uriTemplate in your annotation and you can seprate apis by group

Comment: There is no `tag` or `tags` parameter adjacent to `uriTemplate` on the ApiResource attribute. I _can_ add `tags` inside the `openapi` parameter of the Get operation, but this only visually separates the Item section into Foo and Bar sections, while keeping one schema definition at the bottom.

Comment: sounds like you need to file an issue on their project and ask for advice or an enhancement.